# Keras, Inconsistent behavior when using model.predict for accessing intermediate layers output with spektral GCN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to access output of intermediate layers of Graph Convolutional Networks (GCN) and model.predict is throwing InvalidArgument Error for input value where as model.fit is working fine with the same input.

Here is my code and it using 'CORA' citation dataset from OGB provided by [spektral](https://graphneural.network/) library that provide algorithms and examples for Graph Convolutional network. My code is based on one of the example from the same library, [here](https://graphneural.network/getting-started/)

```
from spektral.datasets import citation
from spektral.layers import GraphConv
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense
import numpy as np

A, X, y, train_mask, val_mask, test_mask = citation.load_data('cora')

At = A.transpose()

N = A.shape[0]
F = X.shape[-1]
n_classes = y.shape[-1]

X_in = Input(shape=(F, ))
A_in = Input((N, ), sparse=True)
X_1 = GraphConv(16, 'relu', name="layer1")([X_in, A_in])
X_1 = Dropout(0.5, name="layer2")(X_1)
X_2 = GraphConv(n_classes, 'softmax', name="output")([X_1, A_in])
model = Model(inputs=[X_in, A_in], outputs=X_2)

A = GraphConv.preprocess(A).astype('f4')
At = GraphConv.preprocess(At).astype('f4')

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              weighted_metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()

# Prepare data
X = X.toarray()
A = A.astype('f4')
At = At.astype('f4')
validation_data = ([X, A], y, val_mask)

# Train model
model.fit([X, A], 
          y,
          sample_weight=train_mask,
          validation_data=validation_data,
          epochs=1,
          batch_size=N,
          shuffle=False
)

# Access intemediate layers of model
layer_name = 'layer2'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)

model_input = [X,A]
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(model_input)
print("\n\nIntermediate_output=",intermediate_output,"\n\n")
```

Here is the Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PLGcn_example4_stackflow_debug.py", line 53, in <module>
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(model_input)
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1599, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 846, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Cannot multiply A and B because inner dimension does not match: 2708 vs. 32.  Did you forget a transpose?  Dimensions of A: [32, 2708).  Dimensions of B: [32,16]
         [[node functional_3/layer1/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul (defined at /home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spektral/layers/ops/matmul.py:33) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_22928]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node functional_3/layer1/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul:
 stack (defined at PLGcn_example4_stackflow_debug.py:53)
 functional_3/layer1/MatMul (defined at /home/mansoor4/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spektral/layers/ops/matmul.py:45)

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

The error message is related to mismatch of inner dimensions for multiplication. I tried to use the transponse for input like model_input = [X, At] to fix the issue but still face the same error.

I am new to Keras and Spektral. I have searched related posts on stackflow and tried many possibilities but couldn't get the output of the intermediate values from the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

The `predict` function of a Keras `Model` has a default argument of `batch_size=32`.
You can solve it in two ways.

```py
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(model_input, batch_size=N)
```

or

```py
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict_on_batch(model_input)
```

In your code, the first dimension of your adjacency matrix and node features matrix will be split into batches of 32. However, the model expects to have the full graph at all times, so you should set your batch size at `N` (which is what you do when you call `model.fit`).

### Explanation

To see why this is needed, think of the operations that a GCN layer does under the hood: `A @ X @ W`. This is a matrix multiplication with shapes (N, N) x (N, F) x (F, F'). Note how the inner dimensions of the multiplications are always the same: N with N and F with F.

Now, if you do batching, you are setting the first dimensions of A and X to B=32. This gives you a multiplication (B, N) x (B, F) x (F, F'). See how the inner dimensions of the first multiplication do not match anymore? This is the error that TF is raising. It's telling you:

```
Cannot multiply A and B because inner dimension does not match: 2708 vs. 32
```

In this case, N=2708 and B=32.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation of the issue. It is resolved after your suggested methods.